# I am a beginer in python Can someone help me with conversion of categorical variable into numerical variables

Tags: python

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder

dataset = [['Verified'],['Not Verified']]

encoder = OrdinalEncoder()

encoded_data = encoder.fit_transform(dataset)

print(encoded_data)

print(dataset.info())type here
```

### Output
[[1.]
[0.]]

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 7>()
5 print(encoded_data)
6 dataset
----> 7 print(dataset.info())

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'info'

Comment: Did you assume that dataset is a numpy object? The message says it's a list and list doesn't have any info method.

Comment: Like I said I am a beginer, I am having a categorical variable with 2 classes 
 verified and not verified. I  want to convert this into an 'int'.

Comment: So I have tried this label encoder first and it works, every categorical columns was converted into numerical ones. I am working on my college project and I am just confused should I go with Label encoding or any other conversion method when I am using the map method, it showing errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try link this

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder

dataset = [['Verified'], ['Not Verified']]
encoder = OrdinalEncoder()
encoded_data = encoder.fit_transform(dataset)
print(encoded_data)
```